# variable in for loop not dynamic

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I made a script where the user inputs a series of letters

I wrote this for loop in my script:

```
#variable that contains the alphabet"
Alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
#the user input
Input1=$1
#the length of the string the user inputs
lengthAlphabetInput=${#1} 

for position in `seq 1 $lengthAlphabetInput`
do

 letterAtPositionLength=$(($lengthAlphabetInput-$position))
 letterAtPosition=$(echo "${Input1:$letterAtPositionLength:1}")
 alphabetAtPositionLength=$(($lengthAlphabetInput-$position))
 alphabetAtPosition=$(echo "${Alphabet:$alphabetAtPositionLength:1}")

 sed "s/$alphabetAtPosition/$letterAtPosition/g" file.txt

done
```

I expected that if the user inputs
./script.sh xyz

that it would change every

- a with an x
- b with an y
- c with a z

but instead it only replaces every a with an x. It skips the rest for some reason.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Your `sed` isn't saving the resulting file anywhere, is that intentional?  Perhaps you're only seeing the final iteration of it and thinking that's the only one that ran?

Comment: That's not intentional, but I don't know how I should do it then?

Comment: If you have GNU sed you can use the `-i` flag to modify it in place.  (some other versions may also support that, but it's not part of the POSIX standard).  Otherwise you can redirect that output to a new file, then move that file back to the original name when you're done

Comment: Wow it actually worked thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `sed` command isn't saving the result anywhere, just printing it to `stdout`.  If you have GNU sed you can use the `-i` flag to modify the file in place.  E.g.:

```
sed -i "s/$alphabetAtPosition/$letterAtPosition/g" file.txt
```

otherwise you can write the results to a temporary file and copy it back:

```
tmp_file=$(mktemp)
sed "s/$alphabetAtPosition/$letterAtPosition/g" file.txt > "$tmp_file"
mv -f "$tmp_file" file.txt
```

Other versions of `sed` may have similar flags to `-i` though, so check your man page for local options.

Comment: Note that on Mac OS X (and BSD), the BSD `sed` supports `-i` but requires a back-up suffix (e.g. `-i .bak`).  GNU `sed` optionally accepts a suffix, and therefore when it is present, the suffix must be attached to the `-i` option.  So, _if_ you have to worry about portability between Linux and OSX/BSD, then you use `-i.bak` which works with both systems.

Answer (score 1):

Your script will benefit from the `y` command of `sed`, which does exactly what you want:

```
$ echo abcdef > a
$ sed 'y/abc/xyz/' a
xyzdef
```

Quoting the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

> ```
> y/source/dest/
>        Transliterate the characters in the pattern space which appear
>        in source to the corresponding character in dest.
> ```

Here's how you could use `sed y` in your script:

```
letters="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
replacement="$1" # don't forget the quotes!

letters="${letters:0:${#replacement}}"

sed -i "y/${letters}/${replacement}/" file.txt
```

Note how this solution requires no loops and reads/writes the file only once.